# MaximumFileSize parameter in Start-EtwTraceSession appears to not work

Tags: powershell, etw

I'm trying to automate some processes around collecting ETW data.  To that end, I'm writing a Powershell script.  The script includes this command:

`Start-EtwTraceSession -Name "leTestSession" -LocalFilePath "C:\Temp\traceit.etl" -FileMode Circular -MaximumFileSize 2000`

However, running this command results in the following error:

> New-EtwTraceSession : MaximumFileSize is required for the current LogFileMode (0x9000002).
> At C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\EventTracingManagement\EventTracingManagement.psm1:93 char:5
>
> - ```
>   New-EtwTraceSession @PSBoundParameters
>   ```
> - ```
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_EtwTraceSession:ROOT\Microsoft...EtwTraceSession) >[New-EtwTraceSession], CimException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 4,New-EtwTraceSession

When I looked at (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/logging-mode-constants?redirectedfrom=MSDN), it suggested that the "Circular" value seems to correspond with a value of `0x00000002`, not `0x9000002`.  I tried overriding that by specifying `-LogFileMode 0x9000002`, but I still got a nearly identical error output (the value of LogFileMode in the error message is now `0x2`).

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: I ran this command without error. Are you running as admin? `Name             : leTestSession
LoggingModeNames : {EVENT_TRACE_USE_PAGED_MEMORY, EVENT_TRACE_INDEPENDENT_SESSION_MODE, EVENT_TRACE_PERSIST_ON_HYBRID_SHUTDOWN, EVENT_TRACE_FILE_MODE_CIRCULAR}
LocalFilePath    : C:\Temp\traceit.etl
MaximumFileSize  : 2000
MinimumBuffers   : 8
MaximumBuffers   : 30
FlushTimer       : 0
ClockType        : Performance
`

Comment: I just retried it in an admin console and I still have the same error.  But the fact that it works for you at all may indicate that I have a local setup problem of some kind...

Comment: The error mentions `New-EtwTraceSession` but your code says `Start-EtwTraceSession`. Seems like 2 different commands.

Comment: Good eye! @marsze

Comment: And this command works fine as well `New-EtwTraceSession -Name leTestSession -LogFileMode 0x9000002 -LocalFilePath C:\temp\traceit.etl -MaximumFileSize 2000`

Comment: I think Start-EtwTraceSession may be a wrapper to New-EtwTraceSession.